# Fazer uma requisição no servidor com 2 parâmetros

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Bom, estou fazendo com que uma pessoa use um "range" e decida um valor, assim que a pessoa modificar o range, uma pesquisa esta sendo feita no banco de dados sobre um jogo e seu valor, uso ajax com php para isso, porem esta dando um erro, voces conseguem me ajudar?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Quando você define o valor da variável 'jogo' antes da requisição, você não coloca o .value, ele ta retornando o objeto do Javascript e não o valor do campo, tente alterar.

Comment: da um `var_dump($_GET);` assim vc ve o que o seu ajax ta enviando. provavelmente a variavel jogo não esta sendo inicializada

Comment: no seu `getDados()` depois do `getelementbyid('jogo')` da um `alert('jogo');`veja se não esta vindo como `null`

Comment: onde dou esse var_dump($_GET)?

Comment: Estou definindo jogo igual defini o valor, quando eu mando so o valor ele funciona normalmente, porem agora preciso adicionar o jogo como um novo parametro.

Comment: Eu dou um alert(jogo) e o alert nem aparece na tela

Comment: Deixa eu lhe dizer, coloca código ao invés de imagem pra galera testar. Veja esse post pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/… Tu acha que vou perder horas digitando seu código pra fazer teste quando você em 5 segundos poderia postar seu código e a galera em mais 5 segundos copiar para fazer alteração nele e realizar testes pra ter certeza que a correção surtiu efeito e lhe apresentar uma resposta correta? Leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

Pelo que entendi só é colocar o .value ao final do document.getElementById('jogo')

```
var jogo = document.getElementById('jogo').value;
```

Você está tentando enviar o input jogo e não o valor do campo nesse código

Comment: Ja fiz com o .value porem continua dando o mesmo erro

Comment: Está constando algum erro no console?

Comment: Super estranho, seu script está funcionando essas partes, só era mesmo por o value no final do elemento. Efetuei uns testes aqui, talvez seja o navegador ou algo do tipo

Answer (score 0):

Teste ai para verificar se a requisição está indo com os dois parâmetros.

"php/select-coach.php?valor=1&jogo=3"

```js
function criarReq() {
    try{
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e) {
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e) {
                console.log("Seu navegador não suporta Ajax!");
                //return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

function getDados() {
    var valor = document.getElementById('coachValue').value;
    var coach = document.getElementById('coachs');
    var jogo = document.getElementById('jogo').value;
    var xmlreq = new criarReq();
    
    console.log("php/select-coach.php?valor="+valor+"&jogo="+jogo);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="range" id="coachValue" value="1">
  <input type="text" id="coachs" value="2">
  <input type="text" id="jogo" value="3">
  
  
  <input type="button" value="send" onclick="getDados()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Amigo, na linha 6 está assim:

```
$jogo=intval($_GET['jogo']);
```

altere essa parte deixando assim:

```
$jogo=$_GET['jogo'];
```

Comment: Cara, não faz sentido retirar o `intval`. Porque você acha que é a solução?

Comment: pelo simples fato de nao saber qual informacao esta chegando. Porem sei que ha um valor invalido ou vazio

Comment: Foi um chute então?

Comment: Não fernando. eu não dou chute. to fazendo a indicação do próprio erro .Acima eu falei que não sei qual informação esta chegando la. o fato de tirar o intval muda a forma como vou olhar o código.

Comment: Sim. `Undefined index 'jogo' on line 6`. Mas tirar o `intval` não vai mudar nada, alias o `intval` vai pegar qualquer valor que ele não consegue converter e retornar `0`. Sua resposta não faz nada. Por isso que perguntei.

Comment: Calma jovem, não sabia que você estava falando em outra língua, não precisa de tradução. Sua resposta caberia mais como um comentário (que é o exato comentário do Jasar que pede para ele fazer `var_dump($_GET);`). E minha pergunta foi genuína, sua resposta (como resposta) não faz nada. E não vou dar nenhuma resposta pois não há informação suficiente para dar uma resposta decente. Você precisa aprender a se acalmar, não te conheço, isso não é um ataque. Relaxa.

Comment: Aprecio criticas. Aprecio ataques tambem. Mudar um intval para outro valor muda tudo. como um campo inteiro vai receber um char? ele vai dar indefinido amigo. por isso deixe o dono testar. é assim que eu faço.Se a resposta nao serve pra você pode servir pra ele.